# Is there a way to create a dynamically object literal value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, object-literal

In other words, let the value be a variable.
Something like this:

```
var a=3,b=4;
var obj = {x : a, y : b};
alert(obj.x); //will display '3'
a=2;
alert(obj.x); //want it to display '2' - how can i accomplish this?
```

Comment: No C++ style references in JS, use methods as others have suggested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it a method:

```
var a = 3,
    b = 4,
    obj = {
        x: function () {
            return a;
        },
        y: b
    };
a = 2;
```

And call it like:

```
obj.x()  // returns 2
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/67NwY/2/

Otherwise there's no native (and supported in older browsers) way to get the "live" value of `a` by using `obj.x`. Another answer here provides the use of `Object.defineProperty` that can do this.

You can apply this to `obj.y` as well, if you wish to do the same.

Comment: If you want to be able to update it with just a reference to obj, you can have the function take a value, like so?: http://jsfiddle.net/67NwY/1/

Comment: @ColinDeClue That's true, but the OP seems to always want the value of `obj.x` to reference the value of `a`

Comment: Correct, and the one I updated still will. It'll just also update the value of `a`.

Comment: @ColinDeClue Very true. I just don't see a point when you can use `a = 2;` like the OP originally had. I just feel like it's unnecessary in this scenario. The OP is probably leaving out code/examples, so it could all definitely be restructured to do *something* like what you have, but not deal with "global" variables

Comment: If you only had reference to `obj`, but not `a` at some point.

Comment: "Otherwise there's no way to get the 'live' value of `a` by using `obj.x`." ... [are you sure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16445155/886931)?

Comment: @DaggNabbit Clearly I am not sure. Wow. Haha I thought I knew the capability of `Object.defineProperty`. Very well played :)

Comment: @Ian, I just hope I wasn't too late with my answer... SO moves fast ;)

Comment: @DaggNabbit Unfortunately, you're right...and this doesn't seem to be a high-traffic answer anymore. Somehow, even when I come late to the game, it is recognized. Well, I definitely upvoted your answer (and updated my answer to hopefully re-worded it correctly, without taking away too much from your answer).

Comment: @Ian, thanks, I appreciate that :) Somehow after all these years I haven't quite gotten the hang of SO, I think...

Comment: @DaggNabbit No problem :) And sorry, I meant to say "Somehow, even when I come late to the game, **sometimes** it is recognized." If you post a good enough answer and/or create enough ruckus in comments, you can get recognized.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one approach:

```
var a=3,b=4;
var obj = {x : function(){return a;}, y : function(){return b;}};
alert(obj.x()); // displays '3'
a=2;
alert(obj.x()); // displays '2'
```

Answer (score 3):

**Make it an object**

```
var a = {
  val:3
};

var obj = {x : a};

alert(obj.x.val); //will display '3'
a.val=2;
alert(obj.x.val); //will display '2'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tzfDa/2/

**Property getters and setters**
Adding to what Ian said, in newer versions of JS, you can use property getters and setters. Ian used the programmatic way of defining them, there's also a literal syntax (since your question title mentions "object literal"). Note that by adding a setter also, we allow setting of the value from `obj.x` and `a`;

```
var a = 3;
var o = {
    get x() {
        return a;
    },
    set x(value) {
        a = value;
    }
};    
alert ( o.x ); // 3
a = 2;
alert( o.x ); // 2
o.x = 4;
alert(a); // 4
```

Comment: Did you test in a jsFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/tzfDa/ You're setting the `x` property as a reference to the object `a`. So the `alerts` show "[object Object]". And if you change it to `var obj = {x: a.val};` it still doesn't work because it's still referencing a primitive - http://jsfiddle.net/tzfDa/1/

Comment: Ahh now I see what you're getting at!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [property descriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) (as of ECMAScript version 5).

```
var a = 3;
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "x", { get : function(){ return a; } });

alert(obj.x); // 3

a = 2;

alert(obj.x); // 2
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b7prK/

Comment: It's the same as methods, but with syntactic sugar

Comment: @JuanMendes It's **not** the same as methods. You don't have to **call** `obj.x`. It's still a property. I'd say that's very different.

Comment: It's syntactic sugar, it is implemented as functions without parameters as you can tell by the fact that you pass in a function and use its closure.

Comment: @JuanMendes It doesn't matter how it's defined...the difference is how you access it. To get its value, you use `obj.x`, not `obj.x()`; if you do `alert(typeof obj.x)`, you get "number", not "function". Simply using methods doesn't achieve this, which may or may not break something

Comment: I am not disagreeing, my point is that the reason it works is because it's implemented as a method and you can use a closure variable.

Comment: I added an example to my answer that's a lot like yours, but it uses the literal syntax and adds a setter so you can affect `a` by setting `obj.x`

Comment: @JuanMendes I see what you're saying. I guess I'm looking at it from the viewpoint of accessing it. Very cool though

Comment: Nice, the other solutions are OK too but using this solution will maintain a simple alert to 'obj.x' instead of 'obj.x()' or 'obj.x.val'.

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: @user2362973 As long as you don't need to support IE 8-

Comment: If you need to support IE8, you can have a separate code path using `__defineGetter__`.